# How to bind variables inside collection literals in Cassandra 3.0 using java?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a java application in which I am parsing data and updating it to my Cassandra 3.0 database. I have been successful so far until it comes to my columns with user-defined types.

My attempt:

```
String statement_update = "UPDATE table SET "
            + "elements = elements + [{name: ? , associations: []}]"
            + " WHERE id = ?
```

elements is a user defined type in my Cassandra 3.0 Database. 
It is composed of name (data type: text) and associations (data type: list).

`PreparedStatement prepared_update = session.prepare(statement_update);`

`bound_update = prepared_update.bind(name, id);`

variables `name` and `id` are of type String.

I have been trying to use a prepared statement to update my table with newly parsed data; however after the data is parsed I am having trouble adding more elements to my elements column. I get error: “Invalid list literal for elements: bind variables are not supported inside collection literals.” How do I work around or resolve this?

I have tried ways of changing the statement_update to `“UPDATE table SET elements = elements + ? WHERE id = ?”`, but I don’t know what kind of list (or even if its a list) to add to my bind statement.

What is needed to satisfy my user-defined type: elements?

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405114/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-a-udt-element-to-a-list-collection-in-cassandra-us

Answer (score 0):

Try another update notation:

```
    session := getGocqlSession()
    err := session.Query(
        "UPDATE table SET mymapcolumn[?] = ? WHERE rowkey = ?",
        mapKey, mapValue, rowKey,
    ).Exec()
```

This worked for me.

I have done this on Go, but maybe this approach will help.